# Grails createCriteria().list(): for linked domains

Tags: grails, grails-orm

So I was wondering how would I search a secondary domain instance if that domain had a variable that was a primary domain instance:

```
def postFieldTripList = PostFieldTrip.createCriteria().list(sort: params.sort, order: params.order)
    {
        and
        {
            'in' ("fieldTrip.location", ["fieldTrip.%${params.fieldTrip}%"]) //figure out how to search by trip location
        }
    }
```

So there is a domain with locations I can add and the Post Fieldtrip domain can call on that particular location normally but how would I create this criteria where I can search by a location name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can reference the field in a bracket syntax:

```
def postFieldTripList = PostFieldTrip.createCriteria().list(sort: params.sort, order: params.order)
    {
        fieldTrip
        {
            'in' ("location", ["fieldTrip.${params.fieldTrip}"])
        }
    }
```

(The `and` is implied and not necessary.)

Comment: I am probably doing something wrong but i get the error: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: @tmurphy Try calling `.toString()` on it.

Comment: That just brings another error saying it cant resolve the property. Does it mean anything if in GGTS fieldTrip is underlined in the case of 
fieldTrip{....}

Comment: @tmurphy Err wait, yeah you can't have those percent signs where they are. Try hardcoding/debugging/printing your field and seeing if that works.  Maybe expand your answer with what `fieldTrip` has, and what `params.fieldTrip` is.

Comment: Removing the ${ } and the % did it. Thank you